# resize an image before upload, using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arrow-functions, reader

I am trying to resize an image before upload, using VueJS.

Something is still a mystery for me: how to work with arrow functions with my other methods' variables?

Here are my issues:
- `this.addimage()` doesn't get called (`this` doesn't exist).
I tried putting this method inside the function, but then I can't deal with `this.` other variables: 
for example, `this.imgpath` isn't set.

Here is the code. I guess I should use 'file' : `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` but don't get it...

```
<template>
  <div>
     <div>
        <form class="form" v-on:submit.prevent>
            <div class="center msb-i" style="font-size: 150%">{{$t('imgupload'))}}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="file" v-on:change="onImageChange">
            </div>
            <img :src="imgpath" :id="mode+'id'">

            <div v-if="imgpath!='' && !imageuploaded" class="spinner-border center" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
            <div v-if="imageuploaded">{{$t('btn.'+mode+'up')}}</div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here are the methods.

```
    onImageChange(e) {
        let files = (e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files)[0];

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.imgpath = e.target.result;
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = e.target.result;

            image.onload = function() {
              var maxWidth = 1024,
                  maxHeight = 1024,
                  imageWidth = image.width,
                  imageHeight = image.height;

              if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                if (imageWidth > maxWidth) {
                  imageHeight *= maxWidth / imageWidth;
                  imageWidth = maxWidth;
                }
              }
              else {
                if (imageHeight > maxHeight) {
                  imageWidth *= maxHeight / imageHeight;
                  imageHeight = maxHeight;
                }
              }

              var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
              canvas.width = imageWidth;
              canvas.height = imageHeight;
              image.width = imageWidth;
              image.height = imageHeight;
              var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

              // Convert the resize image to a new file to post it.

              this.imgpath=canvas.toDataURL("image/"+this.imgext);

              **this.addimage(); //HOW TO DO THIS??**
            }
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        **this.addimage(); //OF COURSE THIS DOESN'T WORK: NOTHING HAS BEEN SET AND IT'S DOING IT BEFORE reader.onload**
      }


      addimage(){
        var path='';
        var urlpath="/newpicpath/";
        axios.get(urlpath+this.id).then(response => {
            path="." + response.data + "."+this.imgext;
            axios.post('/uploadfile',{image: this.imgpath, path:path})
            })
          ;
        });
      },

  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: your title doesn't make sense and you code is too long (not [mcve]) for me. But I *guess* it's because arrow function's `this` binding

Comment: If you need the functionality of a function expression, then *use a function expression*, there's no bonus points for using an arrow function when its the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Sorry, I made the code smaller with only two methods. My english isn't very good either.
The canvas resize part is what I found to resize an image, but if you have any other suggestion, I would be more than happy to try it... Cause I have been swimming here for hours now

Comment: Quentin : do you mean I should be able to replace reader.onload = (e) => { by reader.onload(e){ ?